# module map file not found swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I've these libraries installed using cocoapods -

- PSPDFKit
- PLCrashReporter
- Charts
- MSAL
- GzipSwift
- MapboxMaps
- Socket.IO

Recently I decide to import them using SPM instead of cocoapods. So, I've removed these from `Podfile`. Deleted the `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` and the `project.xcworkspace` files.

Added these using SPM. As I've other libraries installed using cocoapods. So I run the `pod install` again.

Everything was working as expected. But Sometime after switching to this changes branch from other branch something is not working.

Sometimes its give these libraries are missing but I can see that these are already imported using SPM.
But I always getting -

```
module map file '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-bjcrpfbmlnfniicgifsusnjrxcki/Build/Products/Staging-iphonesimulator/PodName/PodName.modulemap' not found
```

- I've clean build the project
- Deleted the derived data and other cache data as well
- Also did `Reset Package Caches`

N.B. I've multiple target in the project. After importing the libraries using SPM I've individually added these in these targets as well.